# Read JSON from assets when file constains multiple JSONs

Tags: android, json, file, android-studio, assets

How to read a JSON from file which contains multiple JSONs?

I mean, I looks like this:

```
{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
}

{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
}

{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
}

{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
}

{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
}

{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
}
```

E.g. I would like to get an array of JSONs or an oportunity to read JSON number 1 or 4.

Comment: If you can't influence the json-file, you can use libraries like jackson where you can customize the parsing but don't have to do everything by hand.

Comment: then add "[" at the beginning and "]" at the end of your stream and you will have the `JSONArray` of `JSONObject`s

Comment: @pskink but what if I cannot modify this file? Is there a way to read JSONs to an array or something like that?

Comment: ok forget what i said, i didn notice the elements are not separated by "," character so what i said will not work

Answer (score 0):

The above json format is wrong.
The correct json format would be

```
[{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
},
{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
},
{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
},
{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
},
{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
},
{
  "status": false,
  "info": "The email field is required."
}]
```

This you can get as a `JSONArray`

Comment: No. This isn't a single JSON - this is a few JSONs in one file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the structure you described, then the easiest solution here would be to split it by two consecutive ***new line*** characters which will get you separate objects which then can be parsed by traditional ways, ie. new JSONObject() ...

However if the file you are getting is NOT generated and there is a human error possible, it is really dangerous to automate a process like this ... Much safer, but more costly to develop would be building objects by checking for pairs of enclosing `{ }` characters.. You can start by finding the first opening bracket and for every next other consecutive opening bracket you ignore one closing on the way until you close the root object.. This can be easily accomplished by a recursion

This is still ***far*** from bullet-proof, but potential error *should* be detected by the final parsing by JSONObject constructor ..